Work-efficient parallelization of matrix chain multiplication?
Consider $k$ matrices $A_1, \dots, A_k$ of dimension $n \times n$, and a column vector $w$ of length $n$.
We want to compute all the vectors
$$
v_i = A_i A_{i-1} \dots A_1 w
$$
for $i = 1, \dots, n$.
There is a very simple sequential algorithm to do this in $O(n^2 k)$ time (computing $v_i = A_i v_{i-1}$ one by one).
This can also be done by a parallel algorithm in polylogarithmic time and using $O( k n^{\omega} )$ processors, by building a product tree over the $A_i$ matrices.
Is there a work-efficient parallel algorithm for this task, i.e. using $O( k n^2)$ processors and polylogarithmic time?
I am not sure even what keywords to search for this problem?

Have you looked at parallel algorithms deciding st-reachability in a directed graph? As far as I know any polylog parallel algorithm  for st-reachability uses $n^\omega$ processors. If the graph has dimension $d$, the st-reachability problem can be encoded in the multiplication of $d$ adjacency matrices and the column vector. For small values of $d< n^{\omega-2}$ this might be problematic?
